# Does the name of an argument matter when defining a function?

Tags: objective-c

Does it matter if I define a function with one argument name in the .h file, for example...

```
-(foo *) initWithId:(NSString *)id;
```

And then in my implementation give the argument a different name because it hides a class property:

```
-(foo *) initWithID:(NSString *)idString;
```

I know that the autocomplete files use .h as the 'basis' for their autocomplete fillers, and while it doesn't apply to this scenario, I prefer to use the property name in my functions to remain as consistent in my coding style as possible.  It makes more sense to understand that getFoo and setFoo both apply to the same property 'foo' as in -(bar *) initWithFoo:(id) foo;.

As far as I can tell, the compiler doesn't have any issues with it, but somehow it seems like it SHOULD matter.

Comment: While it is legal to call your parameter `id` I'd be very careful about doing that given that `id` is already a type in Objective-C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LLVM analyzer in Xcode does seem to care about some things like methods starting with `new` and `copy`.

Here's a sample warning when I name a property starting with `new`:

> "Property's synthesized getter follows Cocoa naming convention for
>   returning 'owned' objects"

(the @property had a @synthesize that created a getter method starting with new).

Answer (score 3):

No, the compiler doesn't care.  Other people who read your code might care.

Answer (score 1):

the only time it really matters is if you have an instance variable name with the same name.

```
@synthesize something;

- (void)methodForSomething:(id)something
{

something = something;

}
```

this will throw an error. obviously the solution is to modify your instance variables naming.

```
@synthesize something = _something;
```

other then that, parameter names dont matter.